# Equivalent of helm-ag-edit with ivy

Tags: helm, projectile, ivy

I've been trying to switch to Ivy from Helm for the past little while. One feature I miss (and because of this I keep helm installed) is the ability to run `helm-ag`, and then to hit `C-c C-e` so I can edit the lines in the file that `helm-ag` matched.

Is there any equivalent functionality with Ivy/Swiper/Projectile/etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this blogpost](https://sam217pa.github.io/2016/09/11/nuclear-power-editing-via-ivy-and-ag/), I found a solution. The real tool that I was looking for was *wgrep* which does the multi-editing heavy lifting that I was missing. Here are the steps for using the [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) backend:

- Invoke `counsel-ag`
- After you've found the search results, run `C-c C-o` (`ivy-occur`)
- Toggle the edit flag of the buffer to enter `wgrep` mode: hit `C-x C-q`
- Once done with the edits, hit `C-c C-c` to commit your changes

This also works with other tools like [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep); use the associated `counsel-*` command. (In the case of ripgrep, use `counsel-rg`.)